# Visualizing True Color Remotely Sensed Images

Tags: python, remote-sensing, multi-band

I am following this [tutorial](https://eo-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/land-cover-map/SI_LULC_pipeline.html#Part-1:) (which is also on GitHub) and I can't seem to understand this line of code:

```
np.clip(eopatch.data['BANDS'][closest_date_id][..., [2, 1, 0]] * 3.5, 0, 1)
```

I am guessing this is how you extract/retrieve RGB bands from a data-object, but I don't get this `[closest_date_id][..., [2, 1, 0]] * 3.5, 0, 1` is it a standard thing? and what each component stands for? 
This is what a single eopatch looks like, it's basically a stack of numpy arrays:

```
EOPatch(
  data: {
    BANDS: numpy.ndarray(shape=(28, 500, 500, 12), dtype=float32)
    CLP: numpy.ndarray(shape=(28, 500, 500, 1), dtype=uint8)
    NDVI: numpy.ndarray(shape=(28, 500, 500, 1), dtype=float32)
    NDWI: numpy.ndarray(shape=(28, 500, 500, 1), dtype=float32)
    NORM: numpy.ndarray(shape=(28, 500, 500, 1), dtype=float32)
  }
  mask: {
    CLM: numpy.ndarray(shape=(28, 500, 500, 1), dtype=uint8)
    IS_DATA: numpy.ndarray(shape=(28, 500, 500, 1), dtype=uint8)
    VALID_DATA: numpy.ndarray(shape=(28, 500, 500, 1), dtype=bool)
  }
  scalar: {}
  label: {}
  vector: {}
  data_timeless: {
    ARGMAX_B4: numpy.ndarray(shape=(500, 500, 1), dtype=int64)
    ARGMAX_NDVI: numpy.ndarray(shape=(500, 500, 1), dtype=int64)
    ARGMAX_NDVI_SLOPE: numpy.ndarray(shape=(500, 500, 1), dtype=uint8)
    ARGMIN_B4: numpy.ndarray(shape=(500, 500, 1), dtype=int64)
    ARGMIN_NDVI: numpy.ndarray(shape=(500, 500, 1), dtype=int64)
    ARGMIN_NDVI_SLOPE: numpy.ndarray(shape=(500, 500, 1), dtype=uint8)
    STF: numpy.ndarray(shape=(500, 500, 20), dtype=float32)
  }
  mask_timeless: {
    LULC: numpy.ndarray(shape=(500, 500, 1), dtype=uint8)
    VALID_COUNT: numpy.ndarray(shape=(500, 500, 1), dtype=int64)
  }
  scalar_timeless: {}
  label_timeless: {}
  vector_timeless: {}
  meta_info: {
    maxcc: 0.1
    service_type: 'processing'
    size_x: 500
    size_y: 500
    time_difference: datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)
    time_interval: ('2019-01-01T00:00:00', '2019-12-31T23:59:59')
  }
  bbox: BBox(((480000.0, 4050000.0), (485000.0, 4055000.0)), crs=CRS('32632'))
  timestamp: [datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 19, 10, 20, 45), ..., datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 25, 10, 20, 40)], length=28
)
More details on Eopatches can be found [here][2]
```

And this is the code for visualizing a single Eopatch

```
## Take a closer look at a patch

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
eopatch = EOPatch.load(path_out +'/'+ f'eopatch_4', lazy_loading=True)
plt.imshow(np.clip(eopatch.data['BANDS'][closest_date_id][..., [2, 1, 0]] * 3.5, 0, 1))
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])

fig.suptitle('Visible spectrum at single timepoint', y=0.93, size=20)
del eopatch
```